# Combine and build array with foreach php

Tags: php, visual-composer

I need to build a multidimensional array using foreach
There is an array with the names of social networks `social_array()`

the result should be like that:

```
array(
    'type'          => 'textfield',
    'heading'       => 'social_label1',
    'param_name'    => 'social_name1',
    'description'   => '',
    'edit_field_class' => 'vc_col-sm-4 vc_column-with-padding',
    'group' => __('Social', 'AS')
),
array(
    'type'          => 'textfield',
    'heading'       => 'social_label2',
    'param_name'    => 'social_name2',
    'description'   => '',
    'edit_field_class' => 'vc_col-sm-4 vc_column-with-padding',
    'group' => __('Social', 'AS')
),
...
etc
```

The problem is that my code gives me only one result, the last

```
foreach ( social_array() as $icon => $value ) :
    $k = array('type', 'heading', 'param_name', 'description', 'edit_field_class', 'group');
    $v = array('textfield', $value['label'], $icon, '', 'vc_col-sm-4 vc_column-with-padding', 'Social');
    $c = array_combine($k, $v);
    $attributes['params'] = $c;
endforeach;
vc_add_params( 'profile_card', $attributes ); // Note: base for element
```

Social if needed

```
function social_array(){
        return array(
            'facebook'      =>  array('label' => __('Facebook','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            'behance'       =>  array('label' => __('Behance','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            'weibo'         =>  array('label' => __('Weibo','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            'renren'        =>  array('label' => __('Renren','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            'dropbox'       =>  array('label' => __('Dropbox','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            'bitbucket'     =>  array('label' => __('Bitbucket','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            'trello'        =>  array('label' => __('Trello','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            'odnoklassniki' =>  array('label' => __('Odnoklassniki','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            'vk'            =>  array('label' => __('VKontakte','AS7'), 'type' => 'text' ),
            );
    }
```

Comment: you basically want the inner array elements right? like you want to be able to loop through social_array() properly?

Comment: yes you are right, these will be the fields

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 2 `foreach` loops for this because the first `foreach` loop gives you all the arrays inside it. then you need to access each array and loop over it.

```
foreach ( social_array() as $array) :
   foreach ( $array as $icon => $value ):
    //Do something with $icon and its $value
  endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributes['params'] = $c;
```

This is the problem, on any cycle you're setting this value to $c, so in the last cycle you're setting $attributes to the latest $c.
If you want $attributes['params'] to contain all the arrays you need to use this syntax:

```
$attributes['params'][] = $c;
```

OR the same but with function call:

```
array_push($attributes['params'], $c);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone will come in handy this piece.
The working option is below.

The task was to dynamically add many of the same type of fields in the shortcode settings via Visual Composer and the vc_add_params() function

```
$attributes = array();
foreach ( social_array() as $icon => $value ) :
    $k = array('type', 'heading', 'param_name', 'description', 'edit_field_class', 'group');
    $v = array('textfield', $value['label'], 'as_'.$icon, '', 'vc_col-sm-4 vc_column-with-padding', 'Social');
    $c = array_combine($k, $v);

    $attributes[] = $c;
endforeach;
vc_add_params( 'as_profile_card', $attributes ); // Note: base for element
```